# Colorbox with JQuery Appended

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am trying to use `Colorbox` for photos populated from facebook, which works fine for the images populated on page load.  But when I use `.getJSON` to load 25 more images and append them to my table, the color box no longer works.  I have seen mention of using the `.live` command but guess I am not following what to do...

Here is my jquery code

```
$(function () {

    $(".photos1").colorbox({
        rel: 'photos1',
        transition: "fade"
    });


    var loading = '<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" /> <b>LOADING</b>';

    $('#get_albums').click(function () {
        $('#ld_ck').html(loading);
        $('#get_albums').html('');
        load_albums();
    });

    $('#get_photos').click(function () {
        $('#ld_ck').html(loading);
        $('#get_photos').html('');
        load_photos();
    });

    function load_photos() {
        var after = $('#photos_next').val();
        var offset = $('#photos_offset').val();
        var gallery_id = $('#g_id').val();
        $.getJSON('get_photos.php?gallery_id=' + gallery_id + '&after=' + after + '&offset=' + offset, function (json) {
            $.each(json, function (key, val) {
                if (key == "photos") {
                    $('#photos').append(val);
                }
                if (key == "after") {
                    $('#photos_next').val(val);
                }
                if (key == "offset") {
                    $('#photos_offset').val(val);
                }
                if (key == "count") {
                    if (val == "25") {
                        $('#get_photos').html('<b>SEE MORE</b>');
                    }
                }
            });
            $('#ld_ck').html('');
        });
    }

});
```

`get_photos.php` returns a `json` string of table rows to the jquery.

Here is just one row of the base html table, but the initial has 5 rows and the `get_photos.php` adds another 5 at a time

```
<table width="99%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0" id="photos" class="photos">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" class="photos" style="padding-top:10px; height:140px; width:140px; border:1px solid #7B7B7B; background:#E9E9E9;"><a class="photos1" href="fb_photo.jpg"> <img src="fb_thumb.jpg" alt="fb_photo" border="0" /> </a> </td>
    <td align="center" class="photos" style="padding-top:10px; height:140px; width:140px; border:1px solid #7B7B7B; background:#E9E9E9;"><a class="photos1" href="fb_photo.jpg"> <img src="fb_thumb.jpg" alt="fb_photo" border="0" /> </a> </td>
    <td align="center" class="photos" style="padding-top:10px; height:140px; width:140px; border:1px solid #7B7B7B; background:#E9E9E9;"><a class="photos1" href="fb_photo.jpg"> <img src="fb_thumb.jpg" alt="fb_photo" border="0" /> </a> </td>
    <td align="center" class="photos" style="padding-top:10px; height:140px; width:140px; border:1px solid #7B7B7B; background:#E9E9E9;"><a class="photos1" href="fb_photo.jpg"> <img src="fb_thumb.jpg" alt="fb_photo" border="0" /> </a> </td>
    <td align="center" class="photos" style="padding-top:10px; height:140px; width:140px; border:1px solid #7B7B7B; background:#E9E9E9;"><a class="photos1" href="fb_photo.jpg"> <img src="fb_thumb.jpg" alt="fb_photo" border="0" /> </a> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div style="width:99%; text-align:center;" id="see_more">
  <input name="photos_next" id="photos_next" type="hidden" value="xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
  <input name="photos_offset" id="photos_offset" type="hidden" value="25" />
  <input name="g_id" id="g_id" type="hidden" value="xxxxxxxx" />
  <a id="get_photos"><b>SEE MORE</b></a></div>
<div id="ld_ck" class="loader" style="width:99%; text-align:center;" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this truly solvable with `.live()`? It seems more a question of re-initialising colorBox after adding new photos.

I see you've accepted Joy's answer but there might be a few ideas below that you might like to consider if only with regard to simplifying the code.

```
$(function () {
    var colorboxSettings = ({
        rel: 'photos1',
        transition: "fade"
    }
    $(".photos1").colorbox(colorboxSettings);

    var loading = '<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" /> <b>LOADING</b>';

    $('#get_albums').on('click', load_albums);
    $('#get_photos').on('click', load_photos);

    function load_photos() {
        $('#ld_ck').html(loading);
        $('#get_photos').html('');
        var data = {
            after: $('#photos_next').val(),
            offset: $('#photos_offset').val(),
            gallery_id: $('#g_id').val()
        };
        $.getJSON('get_photos.php', data, function(json) {
            if(json.photos && json.after && json.offset && json.count) {//or similar
                $('#photos').append(json.photos);
                $('#photos_next').val(json.after);
                $('#photos_offset').val(json.offset);
                if (Number(json.count) == 25) { $('#get_photos').html('SEE MORE'); }
                $.colorbox.remove();//maybe?
                $(".photos1").colorbox(colorboxSettings);//or is it $(".photos") ?
            }
            $('#ld_ck').html('');
        });
    }
});
```

As you can see, there's a couple of uncertainties but nothing you shouldn't be able to iron out.

Comment: Thank you.  Your solution actually made rel grouping work.  I was really wasnt concerned with it, But just to see I tried your solution and was able to get it working with both routines. 

I am still new to jquery.  I am fairly proficient with php, but just learning what all commands and syntax is possible with jquery and javascript in general has been exciting to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind a `live` click handler to achieve what you want

```
$('.photos').on('click','.photos1', function() {
    $.fn.colorbox({href:$(this).attr('href'), open:true,
                   rel: 'photos1',transition: "fade"});
    return false;
}
```

Documentation for [$.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/4vuDC/151/)

Update based on the URL:

You `get_photos.php` is outputting `td` like this

```
<td align=\"center\" class=\"photos\" style=\"padding-top:10px; height:140px; width:140px; border:1px solid #7B7B7B; background:#E9E9E9;\">
  <a id=\"photos1\" href=\"http:\/\/sphotos.xx.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-ash4\/s720x720\/398601_355232294489552_174042505941866_1396720_1688100724_n.jpg\"><img src=\"http:\/\/photos-b.ak.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-ak-ash4\/398601_355232294489552_174042505941866_1396720_1688100724_s.jpg\" alt=\"355232294489552\" border=\"0\">
  <\/a>
<\/td>
```

Change `id=\"photos1\"` to `class=\"photos1\"` on `a` tags as we are using `photos1` class in `$.on` class and change the `$.on` call like this

```
$('table#photos').on('click','.photos1', function() {
    $.fn.colorbox({href:$(this).attr('href'), open:true,
                   rel: 'photos1',transition: "fade"});
    return false;
}
```

and it should work fine. :)

Comment: not `$('.photos1').on ..` try `$('photos').on ..` . Can you provide an url so I can check

Comment: Here is a link
http://www.rabfoundation.org/photos.php?gallery_id=355229207823194

Click "SEE MORE" at the bottom, you will see the images do not load in colorbox

If I change .on to .live colorbox comes up, but the large image never loads

Comment: It's because you used `class="photos"` both in `table` and `td`. It should work fine now. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks,  I had it setup to use class, but in trying to make it work earlier, I switched to id.  Changed it back and it worked.